# Django, problems with overriding model in sites packages

Tags: django, oop, model, overriding

i got problems with overriding of model "Sites", that contains in Sites framefork. I have a form with "Sites" on my site, i need to display names of Sites, not Site.domain, i'm override model, route it to same DB table in "Meta" class and get error, that i cant to understand, code here:

**Model:**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Site(models.Model):

domain = models.CharField(_('domain name'), max_length=100)
name = models.CharField(_('display name'), max_length=50)
objects = SiteManager()

class Meta:
    db_table = 'django_site'
    verbose_name = _('site')
    verbose_name_plural = _('sites')
    ordering = ('domain',)

def __str__(self):
    return self.domain

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Site, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    # Cached information will likely be incorrect now.
    if self.id in SITE_CACHE:
        del SITE_CACHE[self.id]

def delete(self):
    pk = self.pk
    super(Site, self).delete()
    try:
        del SITE_CACHE[pk]
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

**My overrided model:**

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class NamedSite(Site):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Meta:
    db_table = 'django_site'
    verbose_name = _('site')
    verbose_name_plural = _('sites')
    ordering = ('domain',)
```

**and Error**

```
DatabaseError at <my url>

ERROR:  Column django_site.site_ptr_id doesn't exist
LINE 1: ...ROM "django_site" INNER JOIN "django_site" T2 ON ("django_si...
```

Answer (score 1):

Subclassing the model is an example of [model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). It is not possible to 'override the model and route to the same db table'.

A better approach would be to subclass [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield), and override `label_from_instance` to display a site instance as you wish. Then use your model choice field to select the site in your form.